# Retrieve form fields thru Pardot API

Tags: pardot

The Pardot APIs all have a /form endpoint but judging by the docs there is no attribute for "fields". Is it possible to retrieve form fields thru the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

no, currently this is not possible (though I can't wait for it to become so).

Depending on your needs, you may be able to script this with a UI / Screen driving tool such as Selenium / Cypress. We've done this for retrieving a few things that aren't possible via API.